# Why do I receive the warning "Uninitialized record type: xxx"?

Tags: c++, clion

I have received a warning "Uninitialized record type: xxx" in CLion with code:

```
xxx instance;
```

What is the definition of "record type" ?
My class xxx includes primitive fields, pointers and functions like:

```
class xxx
{
public:
    int count;
    Frame* pFrame;
    int GetCount();
}
```

Why is it a record type ?

Comment: That comes from [clang-tidy](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/cppcoreguidelines-pro-type-member-init.html). It's essentially warning you that `instance.count` and `instance.pFrame` have been left uninitialized.

Comment: Thanks! I think I should add a constructor to do some default initialization.